# I am getting "error": "invalid_client" on social_oauth2 when I try to get the tokens through Postman for DjangoOauth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth

I have attached some of the installations from requirements.txt. I am unable to get the token even after changing versions of djangorestframework etc. Please help. I have been trying different things for 3 days.

```
Django==3.1.4
django-oauth-toolkit==2.2.0
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.11.1
docutils==0.15.2
drf-social-oauth2==1.0.8
social-auth-app-django==5.0.0
social-auth-core==4.3.0
```

[image: Postman Screenshot]

[image: Django Administration]

Comment: Can you please format it properly, It's harder to understand.

Comment: The obvious explanation is that your values for `client_id` and/or `client_secret` are wrong.  Where did you get those values?

Comment: From Django Administration>Django Oauth Toolkit > Applications>Client ID/Client Secret. I have added that image also in the edited question.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. The application hashes the client secret on saving it, so we have to copy the client secret and client ID **BEFORE SAVING** it. The hashed client secret gives invalid client error.  Thank you.

This is how the unhashed and hashed client secret looks like. We use the unhashed one.

**Unhashed:**
kvTbqBKuUx6T8V46lsel7bCtN81jRqk64VNi8NSzuZgLekPD14xsw5dH0sdxltp0RV4Qp3F4Ep9TAMf8Zovvh2PouHZrhNVxkHlBqBtWQFwj1HkamApMIxl6ZOGohV9p

**Hashed:**
pbkdf2_sha256$216000$sCPYuUFy236Q$X6Isj5YUWaav511hVdZzef3Aw7vYecM72ruidBkwd4k=